# Ext.Direct File Upload - Callback - Error "Blocked a frame with origin"

Tags: node.js, forms, extjs, file-upload, ext-direct

I am trying to do a form submit, which uploads a file that I read from and then I attempt to send back the data read from the file through the callback. However, I receive the error

```
"{success:false,message:"Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:####" from accessing a cross-   origin frame."}"
```

Hence my callback is never achieved and the data never makes it back to the success callback of the form submit.

I am not entirely sure what that error message means.. and I do not know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's most probably the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) kicking in. Try loading your Ext JS app from the same server as where the Ext.Direct data is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow any of the below steps.

```
1.Either install your sencha app in the same server as your back end.

2.Use below flag in your browser, but don't do it for production (only for development purpose)

--disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access

3. Use JSONP to access resource outside origin.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to use #2. How is this done? Thanks.

Comment: 1.Close your Chrome browser all instances.                                  2.Right click on chrome launcher icon,go to properties at last,then append these flags in the target section like below i have done.    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access --disable-web-security                                                            3.Now you can start your browser again,you will see a warning message just below the search bar of browser,this shows flag has been set.

Comment: Worked for me. However, I see that warning message, but it says "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer." Is that to be expected?

Comment: Yes,it is expected,because by default latest browser does not support cross origin request.,Which is why i already mentioned not to use it in production environment.Just use it for development purpose. For more info :- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing